# where does haskell packages in nixpkgs go?

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, nix

I once used `nix-env -qaP <haskell-package-name>` to search for a haskell package. But since I updated my nix channel some time ago, all haskell packages gone.

To be specific:
qs@BF:~$ nix-channel --list
nixpkgs https://nixos.org/channels/nixpkgs-unstable

qs@BF:~$ nix-env --version
nix-env (Nix) 1.9

qs@BF:~$ uname -a
Linux BF 3.13.0-35-generic #62-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 15 01:58:42 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I wonder if I need to add some other channels which may contain haskell packages. Is there any thing to do with Haskell NG?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I remember seeing in the mailing list (although I cannot find the exact link now) from Peter Simons that the searching has been disabled through nix-env for Haskell packages from the top-level namespace since they are very big and nix-env was already quite slow. Instead all haskell packages are in a separate namespace named `haskellPackages`. For more information, see [here](https://hydra.nixos.org/build/23816503/download/1/nixpkgs/manual.html#how-to-install-haskell-packages). To install a Haskell package like `text`, you can use this command:

```
nix-env -i -A nixpkgs.haskellPackages.text
```

To find a package name, use this command:

```
nix-env -f "<nixpkgs>" -qaP -A haskellPackages | grep text
```

Answer (score 6):

Citing from http://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#users-guide-to-the-haskell-infrastructure:

> Nixpkgs distributes build instructions for all Haskell packages registered on
>   [Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/), but strangely enough normal Nix package
>   lookups don't seem to discover any of them, except for the default version of
>   ghc, cabal-install, and stack:
>
> ```
> $ nix-env -i alex
> error: selector ‘alex’ matches no derivations
> $ nix-env -qa ghc
> ghc-7.10.2
> ```
>
> The Haskell package set is not registered in the top-level namespace because it
>   is *huge*. If all Haskell packages were visible to these commands, then
>   name-based search/install operations would be much slower than they are now. We
>   avoided that by keeping all Haskell-related packages in a separate attribute
>   set called `haskellPackages`, which the following command will list:
>
> ```
> $ nix-env -f "<nixpkgs>" -qaP -A haskellPackages
> haskellPackages.a50         a50-0.5
> haskellPackages.abacate     haskell-abacate-0.0.0.0
> haskellPackages.abcBridge   haskell-abcBridge-0.12
> haskellPackages.afv         afv-0.1.1
> haskellPackages.alex        alex-3.1.4
> haskellPackages.Allure      Allure-0.4.101.1
> haskellPackages.alms        alms-0.6.7
> [... some 8000 entries omitted  ...]
> ```
>
> To install any of those packages into your profile, refer to them by their
>   attribute path (first column):
>
> ```
> $ nix-env -f "<nixpkgs>" -iA haskellPackages.Allure ...
> ```
>
> The attribute path of any Haskell packages corresponds to the name of that
>   particular package on Hackage: the package `cabal-install` has the attribute
>   `haskellPackages.cabal-install`, and so on.